# What is the rank of matrix $pq^T +qp^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $p$ and $q$ be linearly independent vectors. How can I prove that the matrix

$$pq^T +qp^T$$

always has rank $2$?
I've tried several experiments, but still cannot prove it.

Comment: Theit sizes are 1? What does that mean?

Comment: $$\rm p q^\top + q p^\top = \begin{bmatrix} | & | \\ p & q\\  | & |\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} | & | \\ q & p\\  | & |\end{bmatrix}^\top$$

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. They are both n*1 vectors.

Comment: I meant n*1, sorry again.

Comment: The product of this matrix with *any* vector is a linear combination of $p$ and $q$.